# Minecraft nether portal relocation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my singleplayer survival world, I built a large underground base, and stupidly decided to put my nether portal in it at about y=10. I ended up being stuck in a nether cave underneath huge amounts of lava. I built another portal on the surface, but since it's within 128 blocks of my first one, it goes to the same place.

If I place water next to the lower portal to deactivate it, if I then use the surface portal, will it take me to the surface in the Nether? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Do you have any fire resistance potions?

Comment: @ModDL I hadn't been to the nether before on that world. No worries, I resolved it- I just deactivated my lower portal, got rid of all my things, went to the nether, spent 5 minutes breaking obsidian with my hands to deactivate THAT portal, then went and drowned in lava. Not a neat plan but it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your bottom portal in your world, make another portal up above, then go to the nether with that one. Go to the bottom portal and deactivate it by breaking it, and then finally go back to your upper nether portal in the nether and use it, taking you back to your world.

Comment: I did exactly this (months ago, but that's unimportant) and this solution works great. Thanks!